# React testing library, how to get text from element

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a table being built using react testing library

I'm using debug which outputs

```
<body>
    <div>
      <div
        class="table-wrapper"
      >
        <div
          class="table-component__header"
        />
        <table
          class="test-table"
        >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td
                class="text-grid-item"
                data-testid="text-grid-item"
              >
                test table data
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot
            class="table_footer"
          >
            <tr>
              <td />
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to assert `test table data` is there with

```
expect(findByTestId('text-grid-item')).toHaveTextContent('test table dat')
```

but it fails with

```
received value must be a Node.
Received has type:  object
Received has value: {}
```

How can I assert the text `test table data` is there

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Table } from './table'

const givenTableWithElement = (test: Array<TableElement>) => {
    const table = {
        tableEntries: [{ tableElements: test }],
        type: 'table',
        tableType: 'test'
    }
    return table
}

describe('Components should render depending on their prop type', () => {

    test('Given table element is text, when rendered, text table class should be returned', () => {
        const imageTableTest: TableProps = givenTableWithElement([
            {
                text: 'test table data',
                display: {
                    mobile: true,
                    wrap: false
                }
            }
        ])

        const { debug } = render(<Table {...imageTableTest} />)
        debug()

        const { getByTestId } = render(<Table {...imageTableTest} />)

        expect(findByTestId('text-grid-item')).toHaveTextContent('test table dat')
    })

})
```

Comment: can you show the HTML template(not debug output) also

Answer (score 5):

You can just do `getByText('test table data')` without asserting anything.

`getByText` will fail your test if it cannot find the text it is looking for. If the text is there and your test passes, you essentially asserted that it is there even if you haven't used `expect()` assertion explicitly. Though be careful when using `queryByText` (or any other `react-testing-library` method that starts with `query`), using that will return `null`, so if it can't find the text it is looking for it won't fail you test and you will get a false positive.

If you still want to use an `expect` you can try doing something like:

```
const gridItemText = getByTestId('text-grid-item').innerHTML
expect(gridItemText).toBe('test table data')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using findByTestId to query the element. Instead you need to use getByTestId. Because findByTestId returns promise and getByTestId returns matching node.
You can refer the documentation [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/).

```
expect(getByTestId('text-grid-item')).toHaveTextContent('test table dat')
```

Even you can use findByTestId with waitFor

```
waitFor(() => expect(findByTestId('text-grid-item')).toHaveTextContent('test table dat'))
```